# "expected variable name" error when loading data

Tags: winbugs

I am relatively new to Winbugs. 
I get " expected variable name" error when I try to load data with the following model. I could not figure out which variable name in the data was not a varialbel name in the model. Please help.

```
# Normal likelihood, identity link
# Random effects model for multi-arm trials
model{ # *** PROGRAM STARTS
for(i in 1:ns){ # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
delta[i,1] <- 0 # treatment effect is zero for control arm
mu[i] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) # vague priors for all trial baselines
for (k in 1:na[i]) { # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
var[i,k] <- pow(se[i,k],2) # calculate variances
prec[i,k] <- 1/var[i,k] # set precisions
y[i,k] ~ dnorm(theta[i,k],prec[i,k]) # normal likelihood
theta[i,k] <- mu[i] + delta[i,k] # model for linear predictor
dev[i,k] <- (y[i,k]-theta[i,k])*(y[i,k]-theta[i,k])*prec[i,k] #Deviance contribution
}
resdev[i] <- sum(dev[i,1:na[i]]) # summed residual deviance contribution for this trial
for (k in 2:na[i]) { # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(md[i,k],taud[i,k]) # trial-specific LOR distributions
}
}
totresdev <- sum(resdev[]) # Total Residual Deviance
for (c in 1:(nt-1)) { # priors for all mean treatment effects
for (k in (c+1):nt) { d[c,k] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) }
}
sd ~ dunif(0,5) # vague prior for between-trial SD
tau <- pow(sd,-2) # between-trial precision = (1/between-trial variance)
} # *** PROGRAM ENDS

# Data                                                                      
list(ns=15, nt=6)                                                                       
t[,1]   t[,2]   t[,3]   t[,4]   t[,5]   t[,6]   y[,1]   y[,2]   y[,3]   y[,4]   y[,5]   y[,6]   se[,1]  se[,2]  se[,3]  se[,4]  se[,5]  se[,6]  na[]
1   2   3   3   4   4   -0.032  0.067   0.108   0.054   0.136   0.178   0.0149  0.0218  0.0263  0.0264  0.0158  0.0156  6
1   2   3   3   4   4   -0.043  0.069   0.212   0.101   0.218   0.2 0.0156  0.0222  0.0287  0.0267  0.0159  0.0156  6
1   2   3   4   NA  NA  0.004   0.076   0.119   0.171   NA  NA  0.0158  0.0127  0.0126  0.0126  NA  NA  4
1   2   3   4   NA  NA  -0.031  0.093   0.129   0.207   NA  NA  0.0153  0.0121  0.0119  0.0119  NA  NA  4
3   3   4   4   NA  NA  0.149   0.186   0.208   0.223   NA  NA  0.018   0.018   0.018   0.018   NA  NA  4
2   3   4   4   NA  NA  0.121   0.121   0.209   0.211   NA  NA  0.0189  0.0186  0.0187  0.0183  NA  NA  4
1   3   4   NA  NA  NA  -0.045  0.133   0.186   NA  NA  NA  0.0332  0.0232  0.0224  NA  NA  NA  3
3   3   5   NA  NA  NA  0.1 0.08    0.14    NA  NA  NA  0.016   0.016   0.016   NA  NA  NA  3
2   3   5   NA  NA  NA  0.09    0.08    0.17    NA  NA  NA  0.024   0.024   0.025   NA  NA  NA  3
3   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.027   0.066   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.24    0.24    NA  NA  NA  NA  2
1   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  -0.072  0.177   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.06    0.042   NA  NA  NA  NA  2
3   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.052   0.189   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.028   0.017   NA  NA  NA  NA  2
3   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.17    0.34    NA  NA  NA  NA  0.028   0.028   NA  NA  NA  NA  2
3   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.15    0.23    NA  NA  NA  NA  0.0214  0.0205  NA  NA  NA  NA  2
3   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.12    0.2 NA  NA  NA  NA  0.018   0.0182  NA  NA  NA  NA  2
END                                                                         
# Initial Values
# Initial values for delta can be generated by WinBUGS.
#chain 1
list(sd=1, mu=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
d = structure(.Data = c(NA,0,0,0,0,0, NA,NA,0,0,0,0,  NA,NA,NA,0, 0, 0, NA,NA,NA,NA,0, 0,    NA,NA,NA,NA, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5,6)))
#chain 2
list(sd=4, mu=c(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3)),
d = structure(.Data = c(NA,-2,0,5,0,2, NA,NA,0, 2,-5,-2, NA,NA,NA,5, 2,0, NA,NA,NA,NA,         2,0,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA,0), .Dim = c(5,6)))
#chain 3
list( sd=2, mu=c(-3, 5, -1, -3, 7, -3, -4, 5, -1, -3, 7, -3, -4, 5, -1)),
d = structure(.Data = c(NA,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3, NA, NA,-3,-3,-3,-3, NA,NA,NA,-3,-3,-3, NA,NA,NA,NA,-    3,-3, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-3), .Dim = c(5,6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the spacing between the values. I experienced a similar problem and it was resolved by converting the spaces to tabs between the values and finding an out of place space in the syntax.